# What format of json threejs supports.

Tags: three.js

i am just trying to plot a chart using threejs, So i just prepare a data.json as

```
{
    "chart": [
        {
            "Year": "2005",
            "Money": "550",
            "Number": "35"
        },
        {
            "Year": "2006",
            "Money": "600",
            "Number": "40"
        }
    ] }
```

Initilize JSONLoader & calling

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("data.json",function(a){
    //console.log(a);
});
```

and m getting error saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

I m not sure what is wrong here. But as m guessing i think threejs is not able to read such normal data. i saw all other examples m getting model or geometry others are fetching from json. IS there any special format we need to store json data? or we need to use jquery with threejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THREE.JSONLoader class is meant to load meshes in a *special* data format. You can use it to load objects created in Blender, for example. You cannot just load *any* json this way.

You will have to use *standard* way of fetching JSON (jQuery or native HttpRequest class) and then create meshes in your scene with your own piece of code.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some information, such as _examples_ or _documentation_ as to what this _special_ format is, exactly. And you _seem_ to be saying that using an AJAX is essential here -- is it that actually true? Can't you just load _the_ json synchronously as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a generic format for data exchange (like XML), and as @lot says, you need to be creating JSON in the three.js format. Unfortunately it seems this format is [not documented anywhere](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3.0). It can be created using this [blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender), but I've wanted to code some manually without the use of Blender. To do so, I used the examples available [here](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs424/notes2013/threejs/json-loader-demo.html), which load [these json files](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs424/notes2013/threejs/models-json/).

It seems that there was a [decision](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3298) made to start calling threejs json files .3geo, .3obj, and .3mat . However, it seems that this [never happened](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/6ff842c0f4a1fbe99e741ffac6e99ff7749f1f1c/editor/js/Loader.js#L90).

EDIT: Aha, I found some [documentation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3) after all!

Comment: First, I am not affiliated with THREE.JS developers in any way, so it is not my fault that you couldn't find a documentation for json format. Also I think that you don't understand purpose of this json format - it is used by three.js more or less "internally". At least in my opinion it was not meant to serve just any purpose that people might come up with. If you want to load something into your application, then encode and decode it yourself whatever it is.

Comment: Mm, no. If you read the stuff I linked to, you will see that the intent is clearly for the json format to be used to interchange with other programs (Blender, initially), and as the canonical way to store a three.js scene in a file. Sorry I made fun of your italics, that was rude. I think I was annoyed because you seemed to be talking down to the (clearly inexperienced) OP and forgetting that people with more experience will also read your answers.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about purpose of this three.js json format. Thus I hope it is clear that it is not meant for purpose declared in original question. This method is meant for loading of meshes and materials, not charts of Sumant's app. What he should do is to load json containing his chart data and construct meshes and materials from that data with his own code. He is not supposed to sit down with a documentation and write a three.js object json file in his favorite text editor :-)